# Pivot query will only return data from the 'FromDate' and not between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a query as follows:

```
DECLARE @_DateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @_DateTo DATETIME
DECLARE @_SerialNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @_DateFrom = '2018-10-20 00:00:00'
SET @_DateTo = '2018-10-21 00:00:00'
SET @_SerialNumber = '2209'

    SELECT [Serial], 
       [Channel],
       [ReadingDate],
       [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],[02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],
       [03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],[04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
       [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],[08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],
       [09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],[10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
       [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],[14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],
       [15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],[16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
       [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],[20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],
       [21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],[22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00]
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            SerialNumber AS [Serial],
            ChannelName AS [Channel],
            (CASE WHEN 
                    CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE) > CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
                    THEN CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
                    ELSE CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE)
            END) AS [ReadingDate],
            CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME) AS [ReadingTime],
            ChannelValue AS [Value]
        FROM [UriData]
        WHERE ReadingDate BETWEEN @_DateFrom AND @_DateTo       
        AND SerialNumber = @_SerialNumber
        AND ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM [Staging].[ActiveChannels]) 
        ) AS [Raw]
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX( [Value] ) FOR [ReadingTime] IN( [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],
                                         [02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],[03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],
                                         [04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
                                         [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],
                                         [08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],[09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],
                                         [10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
                                         [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],
                                         [14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],[15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],
                                         [16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
                                         [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],
                                         [20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],[21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],
                                         [22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00])
    ) AS pvt    
    ORDER BY ReadingDate DESC, Channel, [Serial]
```

The query only returns data for the @_DateFrom variable and will not return any other data beyond that i.e between two dates, so the above query will only return data for  `'2018-10-20 00:00:00'`. I have tried adding it on SQL Fiddle but the site doesn't seem to be working again. I have a feeling it is the case statement that is causing it, but I am struggling to rectify it.

So I have a Dropbox link that has the query, the data used and the expected output https://www.dropbox.com/sh/odtn35jo6sjhqde/AAChn5Fw7OgrCIyI70XiJ-msa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @_SerialNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2209'   
DECLARE @_DateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @_DateTo DATETIME

SET @_DateFrom = '2018-10-01 00:15:00'
SET @_DateTo = '2018-10-28 00:15:00'


    SELECT [Serial], 
       [Channel],
       [ReadingDate],
       [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],[02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],
       [03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],[04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
       [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],[08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],
       [09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],[10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
       [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],[14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],
       [15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],[16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
       [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],[20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],
       [21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],[22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00]
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            SerialNumber AS [Serial],
            ChannelName AS [Channel],
            (CASE WHEN 
                    CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME) = '00:00:00'  
                    THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, ReadingDate) AS DATE)  
                    ELSE CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE)
            END) AS [ReadingDate],
            CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME) AS [ReadingTime],
            ChannelValue AS [Value]
        FROM [Staging].[UriData]
        WHERE ReadingDate BETWEEN @_DateFrom AND @_DateTo
        AND SerialNumber = @_SerialNumber   
        and ChannelName = 'v1'
        ) AS [Raw]

    PIVOT
    (
        MAX( [Value] ) FOR [ReadingTime] IN([00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],
                                         [02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],[03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],
                                         [04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
                                         [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],
                                         [08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],[09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],
                                         [10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
                                         [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],
                                         [14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],[15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],
                                         [16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
                                         [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],
                                         [20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],[21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],
                                         [22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00])

    ) AS pvt    
    ORDER BY ReadingDate DESC, Channel, [Serial]
```

Comment: This pops the midnight value down, so I can get tomorrows midnight in today's row. For example, if it were Monday I would want the midnight value of Tuesday as the last entry in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this logic:

```
       (CASE WHEN 
                CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE) > CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
                THEN CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
                ELSE CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE)
        END) AS [ReadingDate],
```

If `ReadingDate` is ever *larger* than `@_DateFrom`, then it is set to `@_DateFrom`.  That would seem to be the culprit.

Comment: I have tried playing around with your suggestion and cannot get it to do what I need.

Comment: The reason it's that way is to get the readings in the correct order. I have to have, for example, all readings from 24-10-18 00:15:00 in 15-minute intervals and the last reading on the row has to be 25-10-18 00:00:00. –

Answer (score 0):

I'm gussing that `ReadingDate` is a DATETIME column. if true. Then, your issue is in this line :

```
SET @_DateFrom = '2018-10-20 00:00:00'
SET @_DateTo = '2018-10-21 00:00:00'
```

you're starting from the beginning of 2018-10-20 12AM O'Clock , and ending at 2018-10-21 at midnight (this is a 24 hours). if you want to include the 2018-10-21 in your results, you must do something like this :

```
SET @_DateFrom = '2018-10-20 00:00:00'
SET @_DateTo = '2018-10-21 23:59:59'
```

So, you start at 2018-10-20 12AM O'Clock, and end at 2018-10-21 23:59:59 PM (Which is closer to 12AM O'Clock). (This is 48 hours, more or less).

This will include both dates records.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work as I have to have for example all reading from 24-10-18 in 15-minute intervals and the last reading on the row has to be 25-10-18 00:00:00. Currently, your method will add the reading at midnight of the 24-10-18 as the last entry on the row, which makes the last incrementing value the lowest on the row, when it should be the highest value as it is the last reading. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin update your post, add the expected result from the example provided in your post.

Comment: I added a dropbox link in the question with the expected output as it has 99 columns, it will be used for a CSV file eventually. You will see from the output that while correct, I can only retrieve one day. Hope you can help.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin I can only see 3 files, one of which named (Current output from query) is that the expected output that you're seeking to see in your results ? if not, please use the same sample, make a correct output so I can test the sample and see what's the issue to be compared with the correct output.

Comment: It is the current output. What I am expecting to see is all of the days from the dataset. Let me try and create something.

Comment: I added a file call 'Incorrect but expected output' and used my latest query. I have to have readings from e.g. 24-10-18 in 15-minute intervals and the last reading on the row has to be 25-10-18 00:00:00. If you see from channel 'v1' you can see that todays midnight value has appeared at the end. When in fact that time has not passed yet. Also v1 is an incrmeneting number, so the highest value would normally appear at midnight.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin on your current query, replace the case with `CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE)` and see if that what are you looking for ?

Comment: I tried that and I get data, but the problem still persists. The midnight value from today still appears as the midnight value for tomorrow. I'm stumped!

Comment: I have managed to create a file called expected output for one channel.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin The output for your query is correct, the issue you're experiencing is due to the data source. If you select the data source and checked each 00:00 for each date and compare it with the results, you'll see it's the same (as from your samples). But if the source is also incorrect, then actual issue is beyond that.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin here is picture shows what I meant https://i.postimg.cc/bJ3XrF22/erew.png

Comment: So, in essence, I can only go to 23:45 and cannot add tomorrows midnight value to today's row?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you kind of put me on the right track there with comparing the date/time.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin From your questions, the source data seems to have some issues, and needs to be fixed. While, you can manipulate the records as you wish, but moving the records as you've suggested (as to correct the output) is not a good idea, you'll need to fix the source instead so the affects will be global, and you'll have a solid data source.

Comment: I have found duplicate and null entries (as you suggested) and created a SPROC to get rid of them. So the source is now cleaned. I will run the SPROC before I create the table.